# Magento 2.4: Error on running composer require magento/quality-patches

Tags: magento2, composer, patches

I am getting this error as soon as I enter the username (access key from the marketplace):

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\exec() in phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Helper/QuestionHelper.php:452
Stack trace:
#0 phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Helper/QuestionHelper.php(354): Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\QuestionHelper->hasSttyAvailable()
#1 phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Helper/QuestionHelper.php(137): Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\QuestionHelper->getHiddenResponse(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\StreamOutput), Resource id #1)
#2 phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Helper/QuestionHelper.php(69): Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\QuestionHelper->doAsk(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\StreamOutput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Question\Question))
#3 phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/src/Composer/IO/ConsoleIO.php(314): Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\QuestionHelper->ask(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\StreamOutput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Question\Question))
#4 phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/src/Composer/Util/AuthHelper.php(203): Composer\IO\ConsoleIO->askAndHideAnswer(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Question\Question))
#5 phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/src/Composer/Util/Http/CurlDownloader.php(531): Composer\Util\AuthHelper->promptAuthIfNeeded('https://repo.ma...', 'repo.magento.co...', 401, 'HTTP/2 401 ', Array)
#6 phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/src/Composer/Util/Http/CurlDownloader.php(405): Composer\Util\Http\CurlDownloader->isAuthenticatedRetryNeeded(Array, Object(Composer\Util\Http\CurlResponse))
#7 phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/src/Composer/Util/HttpDownloader.php(404): Composer\Util\Http\CurlDownloader->tick()
#8 phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/src/Composer/Util/HttpDownloader.php(373): Composer\Util\HttpDownloader->countActiveJobs(0)
#9 phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/src/Composer/Util/HttpDownloader.php(109): Composer\Util\HttpDownloader->wait(0)
#10 phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/src/Composer/Repository/ComposerRepository.php(1326): Composer\Util\HttpDownloader->get('https://repo.ma...', Array)
#11 phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/src/Composer/Repository/ComposerRepository.php(1046): Composer\Repository\ComposerRepository->fetchFile('https://repo.ma...', 'packages.json', NULL, true)
#12 phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/src/Composer/Repository/ComposerRepository.php(686): Composer\Repository\ComposerRepository->loadRootServerFile()
#13 phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/src/Composer/Repository/ComposerRepository.php(470): Composer\Repository\ComposerRepository->hasProviders()
#14 phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/src/Composer/Repository/RepositorySet.php(185): Composer\Repository\ComposerRepository->loadPackages(Array, Array, Array)
#15 phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/src/Composer/Package/Version/VersionSelector.php(86): Composer\Repository\RepositorySet->findPackages('magento/quality...', NULL, 0)
#16 phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/src/Composer/Command/InitCommand.php(908): Composer\Package\Version\VersionSelector->findBestCandidate('magento/quality...', NULL, 'stable', Object(Composer\Filter\PlatformRequirementFilter\IgnoreNothingPlatformRequirementFilter))
#17 phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/src/Composer/Command/InitCommand.php(535): Composer\Command\InitCommand->findBestVersionAndNameForPackage(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), 'magento/quality...', Object(Composer\Repository\PlatformRepository), 'stable', NULL, NULL, false)
#18 phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/src/Composer/Command/RequireCommand.php(204): Composer\Command\InitCommand->determineRequirements(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput), Array, Object(Composer\Repository\PlatformRepository), 'stable', true, false)
#19 phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(245): Composer\Command\RequireCommand->execute(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#20 phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(835): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#21 phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(185): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand(Object(Composer\Command\RequireCommand), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#22 phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/src/Composer/Console/Application.php(336): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#23 phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(117): Composer\Console\Application->doRun(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#24 phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/src/Composer/Console/Application.php(131): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#25 phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/bin/composer(83): Composer\Console\Application->run()
#26 /opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer(29): require('phar:///opt/cpa...')
#27 {main}
  thrown in phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Helper/QuestionHelper.php on line 452
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you tell us more about your system, composer version `composer --version`, the php version `php --version` and magento version? Most probably it's related to your installed version of PHP, missing a module. I had some similar error on a new PHP version and fixed it with `sudo apt-get install php7.4-mbstring` (you have to change it to your version of course)

Comment: Composer version 2.2.12
PHP 7.3.33
Magento 2.4.0.

Comment: php7.4-mbstring is already enabled